# How can I predict a new x using coefficient of B-spline basis functions?

Tags: regression, splines

I have a nonparametric regression problem using B-spline basis functions. The range of x is a vector as (350,370,390,410,430). I`ve obtained coefficients. How can I predict the value of response for x=320 which is outside of the range of the original x?
I know I need to evaluate B-spline basis functions at x=320. Knowing locations of knots for the original data set, Is there a way for evaluating B-spline basis functions at a single value?

Comment: Given that B-splines are a device for *interpolating* data, they are not intended for--and can be exquisitely unsuited for--extrapolation.  The more important issue, then, is why are trying to do this?

Comment: Thank you. I want to predict the value of response at a new x.

Comment: The problem is that B-splines are not suitable for that purpose.  Although they can be exploited to mathematically *interpolate* among points, that's rarely an appropriate method of nonlinear regression, anyway, because it erroneously treats all data as being observed without error.